# Checkbox DataBindings - Checked vs CheckState

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, controls

What are the pros and cons of using a Checkbox's `Checked` property vs the `CheckState` property for databinding?

Comment: I just did some looking around and based on a discussion I just read, I'm guessing that the checked property would work better if the field being bound is a boolean type value, and that the checkedState, since it can have 3 states, would need to bind to an integer type value.

Comment: Actually, a DB boolean could sometimes also be null (e.g. a nullable DB field of type bool), representing neither true nor false, so I suggest against using a checkbox for an integer unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checked can only be true or false (presenting a checkmark or none), while CheckState can also be undetermined, meaning a partially greyed checkmark representing neither true nor false.

Nb. When CheckState  is indeterminate, Checked is true. Maybe irrelevant for your situation, but it might still be important.

Comment: I have two databindings available - Checked and CheckState. If I bind my Boolean to Checked and the DB value is Null, what value does Checked get - true or false? It seems obvious that with CheckedState the DBNull would be represented by CheckState = indeterminate. Right?

Comment: I suspect that DBNull results in Checked = false and CheckState = Indeterminate, but your best bet is of course to try it yourself :).